# How to transfer 10kb text into pod in kubernetes with a simple way?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to transfer some key-value data, about 1kb~10kb, into a pod in kubernetes. Is there a simple way to achieve this? I don't want to create a configmap each time, because this will happen many many times...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make a web API in your pod? There's no specific magic answer, how would you do this if weren't Kubernetes?

Comment: looks like a suitable request with serverless/lambda

Comment: yes, before I use kubernetes,  my application will pull data from a http server designed for this. I hope there is a way to eliminate it to simplify my system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with kubectl cp command to copy files into pod.

Other way is to create REST endpoint in the service running inside pod and POST the file to the endpoint.

Comment: You can consider init container but file transfer can be done only once at the start up.

Answer (score 0):

Best method to achieve this is to make a file locally and fill the file with your config (key-val pairs) 
then 
lets say `/tmp/foo.properties` is your file containing key-val pairs locally to mount this file in a pod just copy with following command

`kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo.properties`

your file will be present in `/tmp/foo.properties`

Comment: thank you,  but my pod have to read this data immediately when it is started, and also I have to use API rather than kubectl to access K8S.